# all possible combinations of array element

Tags: java, arrays, combinations

I have an array that contains letters and numbers 
and I want to find all possible combination of array elements.

This is my array :

```
char[] ascii = new char[94];
int index = 0;
for (char c = '0'; c <= '9'; c++) { // Filling numbers
    ascii[index++] = c;
}
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) { // Filling cabital letters
    ascii[index++] = c;
}
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) { // Filling small letters
    ascii[index++] = c;
}
```

and the output I want is something like this :

> 111
>
> 112
>
> 113
>
> 114
>
> 121
>
> 122
>
> 123

and so on

Comment: You want to print the ASCII value?

Comment: Do you mean "all combinations of length 3"?  (94 choose 3)  = 134044 combinations.  It gets worse if you mean "all combinations of any length"...for example for combinations of length-47, there are (94 choose 47) = 1.6257011e+27 combinations, which is roughly 2^90...you won't finish that in your lifetime.

Comment: Oh snap.  You don't even mean "unique" members... that's just 94 to the power of (max combination length).

Comment: How is the output related to your code? Where is the a-z relevant, the A-Z, the 0-9? Why is there this jump from 114 to 121? What kind of combination is it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an aproach to do the job, but it only works if the array only have the space to store the numbers and letters with no free space. By the way, it starts with '0'.

```
for (char a : ascii)
    for (char b : ascii)
        for (char c: ascii)
            System.out.println("" + a + b + c);
```